# Get filename of pictures from PhotoKit

Tags: swift, photokit

I am trying to get the `filename` (red box on screenshot) for my pictures in Photos.
[image: Info Dialog for Picture in Photos with filename in a red box]

I can retrieve all Pictures as `PHAssets`. But i don't know how to access that filename information.

```
import Foundation
import Photos

private var allPhotos = PHFetchResult<PHAsset>()

let allPhotosOptions = PHFetchOptions()
allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [
  NSSortDescriptor(
    key: "creationDate",
    ascending: false)
]

allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: allPhotosOptions)

allPhotos.enumerateObjects { (asset, start, stop) in
    print("######################")
    print(asset.localIdentifier)
    print(asset.description)
    print(asset.attributeKeys.description)
    
}
```

This is all the information i seem to get for each picture.

> 951110A3-D9FF-4922-9155-FA206AA07C7E/L0/001 <PHAsset: 0x14e90bdc0>
> 951110A3-D9FF-4922-9155-FA206AA07C7E/L0/001 mediaType=1/4,
> sourceType=1, (1125x2436), creationDate=2023-11-15 09:01:33 +0000,
> location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0, adjusted=0  []

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what i was looking for. Thanks